# get rss feed data in angular 8 works only for few examples. what I do wrong?

Tags: javascript, angular, xml, rss, angular8

I found source code for rss data on my page in angular.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-rss-feed
But it works only for example 
adress("https://gadgets.ndtv.com/rss/feeds"). Please help.
Console chrome logs

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://news.yahoo.com/rss/' (redirected
>   from 'http://news.yahoo.com/rss/') from origin 'null' has been blocked
>   by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
>   the requested resource.
>
> core.js:6014 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0,
>   statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://news.yahoo.com/rss/", ok:
>   false, …} Why the code doesn't work with other rss feeds?.What change?

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import * as xml2js from "xml2js";
import { NewsRss } from './news-rss';
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  RssData: NewsRss;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  GetRssFeedData() {
    const requestOptions: Object = {
      observe: "body",
      responseType: "text"
    };
    this.http
      .get<any>("https://gadgets.ndtv.com/rss/feeds", requestOptions)
      .subscribe(data => {
        let parseString = xml2js.parseString;
        parseString(data, (err, result: NewsRss) => {
          this.RssData = result;
        });
      });
  }
}

export interface IRssData {}
```

news-rss.ts

```
    export interface NewsRss {
    rss: IRssObject;
  }

  export interface IRssObject {
    $: any;
    channel: Array<IRssChannel>;
  }

  export interface IRssChannel {
    "atom:link": Array<string>;
    description: Array<string>;
    image: Array<IRssImage>;
    item: Array<IRssItem>;
    language: Array<string>;
    lastBuildDate: Date;
    link: Array<string>;
    title: Array<string>;
  }

  export interface IRssImage {
    link: Array<string>;
    title: Array<string>;
    url: Array<string>;
  }

  export interface IRssItem {
    category: Array<string>;
    description: Array<string>;
    guid: any;
    link: Array<string>;
    pubDate: Date;
    title: Array<string>;
  }
```

Other details angular8, vscode as editor, server start with ng serve

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have a CORS Problem.

You can just try to use a CORS extension in your browser and the extension will add the right headers to the responses for you. Here for example, you can find one Chrome extension [CORS Plugin Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf)

see this Answer too:
[How to use a CORS proxy to get around “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)